# Someone please explain the work-flow of the toolchains/boilerplates such as ember-skeleton or iridium

Tags: javascript, ember.js, boilerplate, toolchain

I tried to understand the workflow to some extent on my own but I think I am not satisfied, it would be helpful for beginners like me if someone out there can please explain this...

After cloning the repository https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton
we run the following commands
 `bundle install`  and  `bundle exec rackup`  Then we see our server running, All we have to do is hit `localhost:9292` to see our site running magically. To see changes on the site we add new files in specified folders require them, add css in specified folder etc. I think developers out there have done a great job in easing the development process by developing such great skeletons. 
I'd like to know the process involved. Like, which file  `bundle exec rackup`  attacks on it's launch, like `ASSET` file or `config` file ? and the steps in which the final `js`,`css` etc files are generated. What is role of other files such as `Guard` file `rake` file etc ?

**Note**
If the explanation of ember-skeleton is enough to understand the workflow of Iridium that's fine else can you shed some light on Iridium too. Link to Iridium is https://github.com/radiumsoftware/iridium

**Not sure if this is going to be helpful or so but I'd like to credit bounty for this question once it becomes eligible.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bundle install` fetches & installs all of the project's dependencies declared in **Gemfile**. Once the bundle is installed, run commands in your project with `bundle exec ...` to execute with the bundled gems and not the system gems. (See [bundler](http://gembundler.com/).)

`bundle exec rackup` loads the web app as declared in **config.ru**. (See [rack on Github](https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/%28tutorial%29-rackup-howto).)

`rake` is the Ruby build tool used to run tests, builds, & other utilities. You can see all of the available rake tasks for a project by running `bundle exec rake -T`.

rake-pipeline (with rake-pipeline-web-filters) is a rake task library that preprocesses (concatenates & minifies) JS & CSS according to **Assetfile**, and copies the processed files to an "assets" directory where the web server can deliver them as static files. (See [rake-pipeline on Rubydoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/livingsocial/rake-pipeline/master/file/README.yard) & [rake-pipeline-webfilters on Rubydoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/wycats/rake-pipeline-web-filters/master/file/README.yard).)

**Guardfile** declares file watches, so that rake tasks can be run automatically as files change. Usually, this is used to automatically run tests every time changes are made to the codebase. (See [guard-rake on Github](https://github.com/rubyist/guard-rake).)

Comment: Thank you for your time in answering...I think i'll get going then, I'd like to ask some doubts when encountered

Comment: ember-skeleton seems to be suited for development. Once we're ready to go prod, how can we bundle the application for production ?

Comment: turns out to be ... RAKEP_MODE=production bundle exec rakep minified version of the app will be in the assets folder